# Powershell Excel AutoFilter output the filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a problem I don't know how to access the autofilter filtered data

I thought it would work with "SpecialCells(12)" but I only have the number of filtered data so far and don't know how to get it out

I thought it would work like this:

$Worksheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Cells.Item($i,6).Text.ToLower()

but unfortunately it doesn't work that way

```
# Excel open 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true

# Mappen open
$SourceBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($PWD.Path + "\Inventory.xlsm")
$WorkSheet1 = $SourceBook.Worksheets.Item("Tabelle1")
$WorkSheet1.Range("A8:S8").AutoFilter(13,"abgebaut", 7)

#RowFilteredMax
$RowFilteredMax = $Worksheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Cells.Count

# Datalist 
$Inventory = @()
for ($i=2; $i -le $RowFilteredMax; $i++) { 
$FQDN = $Worksheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Cells.Item($i,6).Text.ToLower()
$Status = $Worksheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Cells.Item($i,13).Text
Write-Host($FQDN + "|" + $Status)
$Inventory += (,($FQDN, $Status))
}

#Write-Host($Inventory[0][0] + "|" + $Inventory[0][1])
Write-Host("Data count --> " + $Inventory.Count)
$SourceBook.Close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: `Columns(1).SpecialCells(12)` likely does not represent a contiguous range, so you cannot index into it using the `Cells(row, column)` method - it just indexes starting from the top-left cell of the first Area in the range.  You need to use a For-Each when looping over a multi-area range.